# Java get class name of arrayList of object and type cast the array list without loop

Tags: java

I have List of objects and need to type cast from class name.
e.g

```
public void foo(List configs){
    //configs type cast code
    configs.forEach(config -> {
        String value = config.getValue();
    });
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Which part of the code is "type cast"?

Comment: You need a `List<SomeClassWithGetValueMethod>` to make it work. You need to see how generic works.

Answer (score 1):

Use a generic type : `List<Config>`.
The compiler handles the generic of raw `Collection`s as `Object`. So it is like if you had declared :  `List<Object>`.

Supposing you have a `List` of `Config` instances, you could write :

```
public void foo(List<Config> configs){
    configs.forEach(config -> {
                String value = config.getValue();
                // use the value ...
              });    
}
```

Comment: but it gives me error "The method getValue() is undefined for the type Object" in for loop. thats why I mentioned for loop specifically.

Comment: @ Joop Eggen Right. I added it.